# Ansible inventory file with same vcenter hostname only takes the last entry

Tags: ansible, vmware

I am trying to run a playbook to create disks on VMs which are on different Vcenters.
so when I put them in an inventory file something like this:

```
**inv.yml:
vcenter1 datacenter=dc1 datastore=ds1 name=vm1
vcenter1 datacenter=dc1 datastore=ds1 name=vm2
vcenter1 datacenter=dc1 datastore=ds1 name=vm3
vcenter2 datacenter=dc2 datastore=ds2 name=vm4
vcenter2 datacenter=dc2 datastore=ds2 name=vm5
vcenter3 datacenter=dc3 datastore=ds3 name=vm6
vcenter3 datacenter=dc3 datastore=ds3 name=vm6**
```

When I run this it reads only once for each vcenter and ignores other entries.
Any way I can make Ansible read same hostname again and again.

I am able to do this with a variable file but I am trying to do this with an inventory file.

Answer (score 1):

> Q: *"Any way I can make Ansible read same hostname again and again?"*

A: No. There isn't any. Change the data instead. For example

```yaml
shell> cat inv.yml 
vcenter1 datacenter=dc1 datastore=ds1 name=[vm1,vm2,vm3]
vcenter2 datacenter=dc2 datastore=ds2 name=[vm4,vm5]
vcenter3 datacenter=dc3 datastore=ds3 name=[vm6]

shell> cat test.yml 
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: name

shell> ansible-playbook -i inv.yml test.yml 

ok: [vcenter1] => 
  name: '[vm1,vm2,vm3]'
ok: [vcenter2] => 
  name: '[vm4,vm5]'
ok: [vcenter3] => 
  name: '[vm6]'
```

Comment: It doesn't take it, it reads vm1,vm2,vm3 as one vm.

Comment: What do you expect? See [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update the question.